# How to define a custom nested path in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named `client` and another model called `client_preference`. The relationship between them is one `client` has many `client_preferences`.
Now I want to create methods for updating and deleting `client_preferences`. For that I generate the routes as:

```
map.resources :clients do |client|
  client.resources :client_preferences, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

and I get the following named routes:

```
edit_client_client_preference GET    /clients/:client_id/client_preferences/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:controller=>"client_preferences", :action=>"edit"}
client_client_preference      PUT    /clients/:client_id/client_preferences/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"client_preferences", :action=>"update"}
                              DELETE /clients/:client_id/client_preferences/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"client_preferences", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Now, I want to customize the routes names from `client_client_preference` to `client_preference` and similarly for other routes generated so that the client is word not repeated twice in the path names generated. Is there a way to do that or do I need to manually define the routes?
Any help or pointers will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `:as` option should allow for creating cleaner named helpers:

```
map.resources :clients do |client|
  client.resources :client_preferences, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy], as: 'preference'
end
```

This should now map to `client_preference`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup this worked, but partially. It only updates the `/clients/:client_id/client_preferences/:id/edit` to `/clients/:client_id/preference/:id/edit`. But I also wanted the helper route names generated `edit_client_client_preference ` also be converted to `edit_client_preference `.

Comment: That's interesting. The `:as` option is supposed to modify the helper route names. The `:path` option is the one that changes the actual path in the URL. I am not sure why you're getting that result.

Comment: Is it because, there is no explicit relationship of `belongs_to` defined at Model level between `client` and `client_preferences`, but only we are using them as `one to many` for our purposes?

Comment: If you are creating a one-to-many association, the Client model should have `has_many` declared, and the ClientPreference model should have `belongs_to` declared as well. Also, if you're using Ruby 1.8 and under, updating the above code to use the hash rocket syntax (i.e. `:only => [:edit], :as => 'preference'`) may be worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah, thats the thing, the model where designed in that way. Now i want to follow the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship between them. I know it not a good design of not doing this at model level. But that's how it was written and actually these both tables live in different db and are connected by just `client_id`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyword `:as` which helps you to create customized path names in Rails. 
Also There is existing answer to this question: [Rails 3 nested resources short name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623142/rails-3-nested-resources-short-name)